# Using absolute path vs relative path in webpack config

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am trying to learn Webpack and when I've watched some tutorials on youtube I have seen them use the path module to resolve an absolute path. Is this necessary? I tried using both of them and it seems that they are the same.
The code from the tutorial looks something like this:

```
const path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: { main: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/app.js") },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    clean: true,
  },
};
```

The code I tried (Which brought the same results):

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: { main: "./src/app.js" },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
    clean: true,
  },
};
```